# Entity framework core generic query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a external DLL with my classes and I would like to make the query depending on the type. I explain better.

I get the type with the function GetType:

`Type targetType = Type.GetType("...");`

If there is any way to make a select like this:

```
_context.Set<targetType>().ToList()
```

Assuming that _context is my DBContext.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that like statement is what you want _context.Set(typeof(targetType)).ToList()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there is:

```
var method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(targetType);
var query = method.Invoke(ctx, null) as IQueryable;
var list = query.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

Well i did something like that.
Here is an example

```
Public class repository: dbcontext
{
 public IDbset<car> Cras {get;  set;} 

Public IQueryable<T> Get<T>()
{
return this.gettype().getproberties().find(x=>.  x.propertytype== typeof(T)). Getvalue(this)  as IQueryable<T>;
}
}
```

Hop this get you started. 
Writen from moble :)